# "The" complexity of "a" problem

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I've been learning English for a long time, but always get bogged down with articles.

> The complexity of a problem is related to the resources required to compute a solution as a function of the size of the problem. The size of a problem is measured by ...

We don't know what a problem we are talking about, so *"a problem"* is used. If we don't what a problem is, how can we use *"The complexity of"* or *"The size of"* then?

Comment: Please wait a day or so before accepting an answer. [This meta question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700) explains why this is usually wise.

Comment: Excellent question, by the way. You've gotten right to the essence of the main role that articles play in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've introduced something, a problem, for example, you have essentially set up a context, and whatever you say next is taken with that newly-introduced context in mind. In context of a problem, there are various things you can talk about, like complexity and size.

> I have a new car. **The** steering wheel is loose.

You know exactly which steering wheel I was talking about, right? You know this because I'd introduced a context in which a car was mentioned. The same thing happened in your sentence, even though the problem comes after the complexity in the actual sentence.

On the whole, you can't describe a certain problem as both complicated and simple; i.e., each problem has one degree of complexity. Therefore, we talk about **the complexity** of a problem. Similarly, we talk about **the size** of a problem.

Comment: the point is that size and complexity are unique concepts for each problem?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko There's only one property called *complexity* (and another called *size*) assigned to each problem, so there must be a definite article before those nouns since you can't be talking about any other complexity and size of that problem.

Comment: It's setting a context. Once you mention *airplane* you can talk about all things related to it: the wheels, the wings, the cockpit, the pilot, the passengers,.... It works the same with *problem*.

Comment: @Clare I'll append it to my answer.

Comment: Excellent answer! It explains, very simply, something truly fundamental about English grammar, which is often hard for non-natives to get, and too "obvious" for most natives see how to explain.